# Train tickets for Schengen visa Itinerary

Tags: visas, schengen

I will be travelling between Berlin and Amsterdam during my Europe trip but I cannot book my tickets as they are not yet opened.

Now in order to apply for my Schengen visa, can I simply simply mention my train travels or do I need to provide a verifiable itinerary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we got our vistas for Belgium-France trip, we wrote a note (in plain format) that we plan to cross the Belgian-French border by the means of local rail lines.

We were told to do that by the clerk in visa office and we've got our visa without problems.

Of course we also submitted hotel bookings for every night on our trip. We flew in (on a promise of charter) and we flew out.